# Why cancelling 6 WebRequest using Task.Start takes longer that Thread.Start

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have custom asynchronous WebRequest class that I am testing to find out how fast the request will be cancelled and found some odd results, that starting 6 WebRequests with TPL and cancelling them right away takes 25 sec, but when I used just regular background threads it took only 5 sec.

**Update**: Running them without cancelling takes with Task.Start 9 sec and Thread.Start 3 sec accordingly.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module2

Dim closeEvent As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim sw As System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

' first domain is invalid
Dim urls() As String = {
    "http://www.jbihgcgfxfdxdwewloevedfhvcdfb.com", 
    "http://www.hanselman.com/blog/",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/",
    "http://www.finderscope.net",
    "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx",
    "http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/"
}

Sub Test1()
    sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew
    Dim action As Action(Of Object) = Sub(url As String)
                                          Dim wReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
                                          RunWebStreamAsync(wReq, closeEvent)
                                          Console.WriteLine("done in {0} ms : {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, Left(url, 50))
                                      End Sub
    Try
        '' Cosntruct a started task
        Dim t(5) As task
        For i As Integer = 0 to 5
            t(i) = New Task(action, urls(i)) 
        Next
        For Each tsk In t
            tsk.Start()
        Next
        closeEvent.Set()
        Task.WaitAll(t)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("total in {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub

Dim WaitCount As Integer = 6
Sub Test2()
    sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew
    For i As Integer = 0 to 5
        StartThread(urls(i))
    Next
    closeEvent.Set()
    Do While WaitCount > 0
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("total in {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub StartThread(ByVal url As String)
    Dim trd As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    trd.IsBackground = True
    trd.Start(url)
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadTask(ByVal arg As Object)
    Dim url As String = arg
    Try
        Dim wReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        RunWebStreamAsync(wReq, closeEvent)
    Catch 
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("done in {0} ms : {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, Left(url, 50))
    Interlocked.Decrement(WaitCount)
End Sub

Public Sub RunWebStreamAsync(ByVal wr As WebRequest, ByVal CloseTask As ManualResetEvent)
    Dim hwra As New MyWebRequest
    hwra.LoadAsync(wr)
    Do While hwra.AsyncOperationInProgress
        If CloseTask.WaitOne(1000) = True Then
            If hwra.CancellationPending = False Then
                hwra.CancellationPending = True
                wr.Abort()
            End If
        Else
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Class MyWebRequest
    Public Property CancellationPending As Boolean
    Public Property AsyncOperationInProgress As Boolean

    Public Sub LoadAsync(ByVal req As WebRequest)
        AsyncOperationInProgress = True
        ' Invoke BeginGetResponse on a threadpool thread, as it has
        ' unpredictable latency
        Dim bgrd = (New WaitCallback(AddressOf Me.BeginGetResponseDelegate))
        bgrd.BeginInvoke(req, Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub

    ' Solely for calling BeginGetResponse itself asynchronously. 
    Private Sub BeginGetResponseDelegate(ByVal arg As Object)
        If CancellationPending Then
            PostCompleted(Nothing, True)
        Else
            Dim req As WebRequest = DirectCast(arg, WebRequest)
            req.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf GetResponseCallback), req)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PostCompleted(ByVal p1 As Object, ByVal p2 As Boolean)
        AsyncOperationInProgress = False
        ' do something
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetResponseCallback(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
        If CancellationPending Then
            PostCompleted(Nothing, True)
        Else
            Try
                ' Continue on with asynchronous reading.
                PostCompleted(Nothing, True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Since this is on a non-UI thread, we catch any exceptions and
                ' pass them back as data to the UI-thread. 
                PostCompleted(ex, False)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

Comment: You should call `Thread.Join` instead of `Sleep` and `WaitCount`.

Comment: with Thread.Join i will be waiting first one to complete than second, i wanted to be independent

Comment: What difference does it make? Either way, you're waiting for them all to complete.  Calling `Join()` does not affect the target threads at all; they will still run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to the fact that your Tasks are only started when the Task scheduler decides it should start them - while the Threads are all started immediately by your code.

In the case where you cancel immediately, this code below is a busy loop - when `CloseTask` is set, then this loop contains no `Sleep`-time:

```
  Do While hwra.AsyncOperationInProgress
        If CloseTask.WaitOne(1000) = True Then
            If hwra.CancellationPending = False Then
                hwra.CancellationPending = True
                wr.Abort()
            End If
        Else
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End If
    Loop
```

Since this code loops taking lots of CPU cycles, then this will discourage the Task scheduler from starting new Tasks - so that's why the tasks get executed in series (hence why your test takes so long).

To improve perfromance, some ideas you could try are:

- at a trivial level, put a `Sleep` in that busy loop.
- check if the CloseTask event is set before calling hwra.LoadAsync(wr)
- ensure that `WebRequest.Abort` is called when CloseTask is set (this is hinted at in your code sample, but it's not complete)
- rearchitect so that the web requests respond back using completed events instead of using threads to busy poll the `AsyncOperationInProgress` flag - if you are using a thread to monitor each asyncIO, then you may as well just use Sync IO.